# Trying to search for multiple file extensions in command line

Tags: search

I am trying to find two extensions in command line but when i do it will only return one of the extensions. can you tell me what I am missing?

Here is my command;

```
[root]# find /etc -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -type f -mtime +7 -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way that `find` evaluates logical tests, you likely need to group the `-name` tests using [escaped] parentheses to get the desired behavior:

```
find /etc \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" \) -type f -mtime +7 -exec echo {} \;
```

I'm assuming you're using `echo` as a placeholder for some other `-exec` action that you wish to perform, otherwise you could simply use

```
find /etc \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" \) -type f -mtime +7 -print
```